# Getting php_network_getaddress error : No such host is known?

Tags: theme-development, errors, warnings

I am working on wordpress theme on my localhost. I started receiving this error.

Its is very annoying and i have no idea to resolve this thing.

[image]

Comment: Probably a broken feed request (Twitter or some blog).

Comment: @toscho i am not using any such kind of widget. shall i reinstall wordpress on my localhost or is there any other solution for it.

Comment: Disable the feed dashboard widgets.

Comment: @toscho -  O yes, all these errors are because of these feed widgets on dashboard. It doesn't show any option to delete them. But still i have unchecked the option 'show content' and its fine except for plugins feed widget. Plugins feed widget has no option to configure it.

Comment: Upper right corner: _Screen Options_.

Comment: You just removed the symptom. _Why_ you get this errors and other don’t – that’s still open. But probably a problem with your server setup.

Comment: You can increase [xdebug.collect_params](http://xdebug.org/docs/all#collect_params) to see in trace which variables are getting passed and are problematic.